Computing Periods Of A Differential 1-Form
Define $\varphi_k(z)=(1-z^2)(1-k^2z^2)$ where $0<k<1$. Then the compactification of the Riemann surface $\mathcal{R}=\{(z,w):w^2=\varphi_k(z)\}$ of $\varphi_k$, $\bar{\mathcal{R}}$ is an elliptic curve and homeomorphic to a torus. We constructed $\bar{\mathcal{R}}$ by cutting between the branches $1,k^{-1}$ and $-1,-k^{-1}$. $A$ cycle of $\bar{\mathcal{R}}$ is the horizontal cycle with parts that go from $-1$ to $1$ with the positive square root $A_+$ and other part going from $1$ to $-1$ with the negative square root $A_-$. Similarly $B$ is a cycle with parts $B_+,B_-$ that go from $1\to k^{-1}$ and $k^{-1}\to 1 $ respectively. Consider the differential $1$-form $$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2z^2}{1-z^2}}dz=\frac{1-k^2z^2}{w}dz.$$
I am asked to calculate the $A$ and $B$ periods of $\omega$, which are given by
$$\int_A \omega \qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_B \omega $$
respectively. The answers should be in terms of complete elliptic integral of first kind $K$ and second kind $E$.
My Attempt:
$i)$ The calculation of $\int_A \omega$ is really straightforward and done as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_A \omega=\int_{A_+} \omega+\int_{A_-} \omega&=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}dx+\int_{1}^{-1}-\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=4E(k).
\end{align*}
The answer is indeed correct according to the book.
$ii)$ Author describes this part "a little difficult" and no correct answer is given in the text. My attempt is as follows. Decomposing the integral on $B$, we get
\begin{align*}
\int_{B}\omega=\int_{B_+}\omega+\int_{B_-}\omega&=\int_{1}^{k^{-1}}\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}dx+\int_{k^{-1}}^{1}-\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}dx\\
&=2\int_{1}^{k^{-1}}\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}dx.
\end{align*}
Now we do the substitution $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k'^2t^2}}$, where $t\ge0$ and $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ is the familiar complementary modulus. As $x$ moves from $1\to k^{-1}$, $t$ moves from $0\to 1$. A bit of a messy calculation shows
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2x^2}{1-x^2}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{t^2}}=i\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{k'^2t}{\left( \sqrt{1-k'^2t^2} \right)^3}.$$
Here we considered the argument of $t^2-1$ while moving $i$ out of the square root. Putting all these together we have
$$\int_B \omega=2ik'^2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\left( \sqrt{1-k'^2t^2} \right)^3}dt.$$
Multiplying both numerator and denominator of the integrand with $\sqrt{1-t^2}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2ik'^2}\int_B \omega&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t^2}{(1-k'^2t^2)\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k'^2t^2)}}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1-k'^2t^2)\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k'^2t^2)}}dt-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2}{(1-k'^2t^2)\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k'^2t^2)}}dt\\
&=\Pi\left(k'^2,k'\right)-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2}{(1-k'^2t^2)\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k'^2t^2)}}dt,
\end{align*}
where $\Pi$ is the complete elliptic integral of third kind. To evaluate the second integral, we differentiate in the definition of $K(k)$,
$$K(k)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}dt\implies \frac{dK}{dk}(k)=k\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\left( \sqrt{1-k^2t^2} \right)^3}dt.$$
Thus the second integral is equal to $\frac{1}{k'}\frac{dK}{dk}(k')$.
This implies that
$$\int_{B}\omega=2ik'^2\Pi\left( k'^2,k' \right)-2ik'\frac{d K}{dk}(k').$$
My Question
I believe that my solution is not the intended one because there is no mention of the function $\Pi$ and derivatives of elliptic integrals are introduced in a later exercise in the book. So i can't use the relation $\frac{dK}{dk}=\frac{E-k'^2 K}{k k'^2}$. I am confident that i should be using the substitution $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k'^2t^2}}$ since it has already been used in the book while computing the periods of the $1$-form $\omega_1=\frac{dz}{w}$. I think it is correct up to the point
$$\int_B \omega=2ik'^2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\left( \sqrt{1-k'^2t^2} \right)^3}dt$$
but i don't know how to express to above integral in terms of $E,K$. For reference i am using the book Takashi Takabe Elliptic Integrals and Elliptic Functions. Any help is appreciated.

Maybe I’m confused but on your first equality defining the 1-form, I think you have forgotten to divide by $1-z^2$ on the right no? I don’t think this affects the rest of your computations

Since $w=\sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-k^2z^2)}$, we get $\sqrt{\frac{1-k^2z^2}{1-z^2}}=\frac{1-k^2z^2}{\sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-k^2z^2)}}=\frac{1-k^2z^2}{w}$.
